# Echo value in query from a wordpress database

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress

I'm creating a options form or my wordpress theme and I seem to be stuck on a bit of query.

I've created a fiddle to show you what I'm doing, you'll notice the value is being populated by a php script, rather than show the php script, I want it to show the value from the database, If I use the same form in html it works, in jquery it doesn't

Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/33Ks6/

Here's the code I used in the html page which worked:

```
function kandibox_hero_upload_image_link_callback($args) {

$hero_options = get_option( 'kandibox_theme_hero_options' ); ?>
<div id='image_uploads_group'>
  <div id="imagebox_1">
 <label for="upload_image">
   <input id="show_upload_image_link_1" type="text" size="36" name="kandibox_theme_hero_options[show_upload_image_link_1]" value="<?php echo $hero_options['show_upload_image_link_1']; ?>" /> 
   <input id="show_upload_image_link_1_button" class="button upload_images" type="button" value="Upload Image" />
   <span class="description">Slide 1</span>
 </label>
 </div>
</div>

<?php
}
```

The important line is :

```
value="<?php echo $hero_options['show_upload_image_link_1']; ?>"
```

Here's how I pout it in jquery:

```
value=\" <?php echo $hero_options['show_upload_image_link_1']; ?> \"
```

Comment: You may have to change the variable from php to javascript - try using the php to javascript method: `var javascript_variable = "<?= $php_variable ?>";` - It's just a thought - give it a try (not an expert on javascript so...)

Comment: @Justice Thanks but it still shows the php script and not the data.

Comment: Is your JS inline or an external file?

Comment: It's and external file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote your code in a file called cosa.php, then I executed the file, and I get the variable...

```
<?php

function kandibox_hero_upload_image_link_callback($args) {
$hero_options['show_upload_image_link_1'] = 'HOLA';
?>
<div id='image_uploads_group'>
  <div id="imagebox_1">
 <label for="upload_image">
   <input id="show_upload_image_link_1" type="text" size="36" name="kandibox_theme_hero_options[show_upload_image_link_1]" value="<?php echo $hero_options['show_upload_image_link_1']; ?>" />
   <input id="show_upload_image_link_1_button" class="button upload_images" type="button" value="Upload Image" />
   <span class="description">Slide 1</span>
 </label>
 </div>
</div>

<?php
}

echo kandibox_hero_upload_image_link_callback($args = null);
```

How are you calling your script? Could you execute this and explain what happens?

### UPDATE

Ok, based on your comment, your problem is that the server DOESN'T interpret PHP if you're in a .JS file, because it thinks is a plain text file. If you need it the value, you have two workarounds:

- Change the .js extension for a .php extension. This is ugly, and doesn't allow you to cache the file when you're calling it.
- Output the value in a hidden DOM element, or as a data-value attribute in a DOM element, and then retrieve it via jQuery. I always prefer this method. To do this, in the main script you output the form, you add to the input an attribute called, for example, data-thumb, and then get it with a $('input.some_class_to_select_it').attr('data-thumb').

### UPDATE 2: The example, :D

For the second option:

- Your HTML form from a PHP file should have the data-thumb and a class to grab it:

  `<input data-thumb="<?php echo ... ?>" class="input_thumb">`
- Your jQuery form your .js file wil grab the attribute and write it into the input:

  `$('input.input_thumb').each( function() {
      $(this).val( $(this).attr('data-thumb');
  });`

I added the `.each()` because this way you may use it in more than one element in your page just adding the class and the data-thumb to any input you want

Comment: Hi thanks for getting back to me, this html form works fine, I'm having trouble trying to port it into jquery

Comment: why? what's is your problem?

Comment: I want to use this value="<?php echo $hero_options['show_upload_image_link_1']; ?>" in my js file, but instead of echoing i.e. HOLA, it echo's<?php echo $hero_options['show_upload_image_link_1']

Comment: Ummm, check the update in the answer, I think that will solve your problem

Comment: Thanks, the second option seems perfect, does that mean I have to create the forms in HTML then hide them? i.e click add and it un-hides the next form? Do you have a working example?

Comment: I added an example I think will help you with it, if not, tell me, XD

Comment: Hi, playing about with your example now and although it was missing a ) I cannot get it to work, I've never used this before so I'm not even sure i'm inputting it correctly.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/47934/discussion-between-chococroc-and-dan)

Answer (score 0):

You either need to make the relevant JS inline in your HTML/PHP file so that you can `echo` PHP variables directly into the code, or you need to use AJAX.

PHP is a server-side language so when a page is requested the server renders the PHP and sends it to the client browser.  JS is typically a client-side language (such as in this case) and is thus executed on the client side in the browser after this happens.

This means they can't communicate without special protocols like AJAX (otherwise, you'd be able to inject PHP scripts to webservers by executing JS in your browser).

If you inline the JS into your php template file you can `echo` PHP statements into it like your code already is - these statements are evaluated when the initial request is sent so the variable value will be rendered into the code before the JS is executed.

Otherwise you need to write a JS AJAX function that requests the value from a PHP script.  This is obviously going to be more work particularly if you aren't familiar with AJAX (although [jQuery has great AJAX functionality built in](http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/))